# Допустим ли хардкод из предметной области?

Tags: чистый-код

Столкнулся с тем, что иногда приходится в проектах хардкодить "магические числа" из предметной области. Не знаю как с ними быть.
Самый очевидный пример - часы в минуты

```
float minutes2hours(float hours){
    return hours*60;
}
```

Для нас с вами понятно, что 60 минут в часе это то, что не скоро изменится и название функции говорит о том, что можно оставить это в таком виде,и это поймёт любой читающий.

Однако, есть вещи, которые столь же очевидны, но только тем, кто знает предметную область. Скажем смена шахтёра не может превышать 6 часов законодательно и тогда метод, который за этим следит будет таким :

```
bool isWorkerShiftContinue(float timeOfWork){
    return (bool)(timeOfWork <= 6*60);
}
```

И что это за 6*60 ?!  Я чувствую себя не комфортно, оставляя это так.
Я могу это вынести в переменную, но тогда их не напасёшься и в коде снова чёрт ногу сломит. Особенно в методах, которые высчитывают что-то сложное. Более того, возникает вопрос, а что если через полгода им сократят время работы до 5 часов??
Помогите, **где та мера, когда можно хардкодить данные, которые относятся к предметной облсти?**

ЗЫ c++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Независимо от предметной области, лучше никогда не хардкодить "магические константы" прямо в том месте, где они используются.

- Что используется только в данном файле/классе - просто выносится в начало кода, там, где лежат константы, и там прописывается именованной константой.
- Что используется в нескольких файлах - выносится опять же в виде констант в отдельный файл, который можно подключить во всех файлы кода, где это будет использоваться.
- Что должно иногда меняться пользователями, так, чтобы можно было поменять это без перекомпиляции программы - можно вынести в конфиг-файл.
- Что должно меняться как-то централизовано в локальной сети, или скажем что может представлять из себя несколько наборов конфигураций, которые могут переключаться в зависимости от каких-то условий - можно вынести в БД.

Повторюсь: предметная область или нет - это не важно, "магические константы", конфигурации и всё прочее должны рассматриваться единообразно, с точки зрения наилучшей архитектуры кода.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно использовать именованые константы. И, если одного имени кажется недостаточно для фиксации смысла, дополнять их комментарием.

(пример псевдокодом - я не уверен, на каком языке примеры из вашего вопроса, и как правильно в нём задавать константы и комментарии)

```
const MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60

// Максимальная продолжительность смены шахтёра согласно закону N...
const MINER_SHIFT_MAX_HOURS = 6

bool isWorkerShiftContinue(float timeOfWork){
    return (bool)(timeOfWork <= MINER_SHIFT_MAX_HOURS * MINUTES_IN_HOUR);
}
```

Comment: можно ли это выносить в конфиг? или любой другой внешний источник или в отдельный хедер? И можно ли в таком случае это делать define-ами

Comment: Я бы в этом случае и перемноженные значения вынес в именованную константу тоже )  А в названии аргумента зашил минуты.

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Зависит от того, как часто это может меняться. И сколько есть таких конфигураций. Если она одна и меняется раз в полгода, то нет смысла возиться к конфигами. Если часто и в любой момент может поменяться и много конфигураций - лучше положить в БД. В промежуточных случаях - в конфиг класть. Ну, количество минут в часе точно вряд ли поменяется, его можно и в `define`.